# how to proxy https connections to http?

Tags: linux, centos, proxy

I have an Apache web server running with both HTTP and HTTPS connections.
I would like to disable the direct HTTPS connection and configure a local proxy server that will receive the HTTPS connection from the client and will communicate with the web server on port 80 ONLY.

Comment: Why don't you simply configure SSL in the same site so it works both with and without HTTPS?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with that configuration?

Comment: What proxy do you want to use?  Why do you want to use it?  The Apache stuff seems easy.  Just disable the https virtual host, and stop Apache from listening on port 443.  After that just do the needful.

Comment: I want to simulate LB SSL termination. I don't want the HTTPS connection to go all the way from the client to the web server. I want the client to communicate with the Proxy on port 443 and I want the proxy to switch the 443 connection to port HTTP. I'm using only one web server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound) is one of the most popular reverse proxy, load balancer and HTTPS front-end for Web server(s).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is something like nginx or haproxy in front of your web server. Both can be configured to accept HTTP or HTTPS connections and communicate to the backend server only through HTTP.